# What is the consequence of the period in this line of bash script?

Tags: bash

I am running a bioinformatics web application on a compute cluster and I'm trying to troubleshoot some issues. The webapp runs a predefined shell script that passes cluster compute parameters (stored in a file named `defaultJobRunner.sh` before running the computationally-intensive work.

For each job that is created, an accompanying shell script is created which contains the following line:

```
[ -f "/home/galaxy/defaultJobRunner.sh" ] && . /home/galaxy/defaultJobRunner.sh
```

I understand this to be short-form for "if the file in the square brackets is a regular file, then run it. What I don't understand is the function or significance of that period between `&&` and `/home/galaxy/defaultJobRunner.sh`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to understand a line in .bashrc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793640/unable-to-understand-a-line-in-bashrc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's short for `source`. It runs `/home/galaxy/defaultJobRunner.sh` as though each line had been typed into the current session. ([source](http://ss64.com/bash/period.html))

Comment: Super, thanks a bunch! I'll accept this as soon as the timer allows.